# Encapsulate Core Data Object's data?

Tags: swift, core-data

Is it a good practice to encapsulate a Core Data Model's data? just like you would in any other class, and implement getters and setters to retrieve and set data to it?

For example:

```
public class MyModel: NSManaged {
   var name: String {
       get { self._name }
       set { self._name = newValue }
   }
}

extension MyModel {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<MyModel> {
        return NSFetchRequest<MyModel>(entityName: "MyModel")
    }

    @NSManaged fileprivate var _name: String
}
```

Comment: No and what do you mean with _"...just like you would in any other class"_?

Comment: I meant any other class, where you would like to encapsulate its data.

Comment: And why would you like to encapsulate data in your classes, that is what I am wondering? Are you a java programmer? ;)

Comment: Haha, I did use to be a Java programmer, but a long time ago; I would encapsulate data when I want to set custom getters and setters, but from what I'm reading that's unnecessary or a practice to do it in Swift, is that right? Anyway, I was just wondering since I've been making changes to my Models and had the question if that's a common practice, but thank you!

Comment: Swift standard is to not implement get/set method unless of course you have some special logic you want to apply.

Comment: Thank you Joakim, that was helpful!